# Semantic UI - Vertical centering a div

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Are there any known ways to center a `<div>` tag using [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/)'s web development framework, without adding my own CSS styles?

I have tried several position-related tags in the [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html), such as `<div class="centered grid'>`, however these only work for horizontal centering.

This is not a case of challenging implementation, I am just surprised something as common as vertical centering isn't included within a web development framework, and I am curious if my Google searches and eyes have glazed over it. I would prefer to comply to the framework styles before creating custom styles. I know that there are several methods to implement my own vertical centering (this is the least preferable option in my opinion to implement), however I would prefer to use a class from the framework.

Answer (score 7):

As per *Semantic UI v2.2.2*, you can force vertical alignment in the middle by adding `middle aligned` class(es). It affects the following elements:

- [table](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html#vertical-alignment), its rows and cells,
- [grid](http://semantic-ui.com/examples/grid.html), its rows and columns,
- [image](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/image.html#vertically-aligned),
- [list](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/list.html#vertically-aligned) and [item](http://semantic-ui.com/views/item.html#vertical-alignment) with an image,
- modal dialog content.

You *cannot* set vertical alignment in the middle that way to an arbitrary `div` element, outside any of these structures.

Otherwise, some other Semantic UI elements align their content vertically in the middle by default:

- [header](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/header.html#image) or [message](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/message.html#icon-message) with an icon or image,
- [circular segment](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html#circular),
- [step](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/step.html),
- [button](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html) etc.

Comment: In my case `<div class="ui three column middle aligned grid">` finally saved me!! Thank you @Kemi :)